# Cant install anything BC Bill of Material for Imac

Tags: macos

I am having a serious problem installing any upgrades or any thing to my IMac OS X 10.3.9. Everytime i have something download and i try to install and it says "The Bill of Material for this Package was not found."

Comment: You bought one ancient Mac. This software might not even be compatible

Comment: Why are you running such a 6-year-old PowerPC machine as your first Mac? You can pick up a used Intel-based Mac mini that can run Lion for well under $500. Keeping ancient hardware and OSes running, and getting the latest software to install on old OSes, is a sport for nerdy hobbyists who love the platform too much, not new users.

Answer (score 1):

That message usually mean one of two things:

1. Mac OS needs to be reinstalled
2. [The software you are trying to run is not compatible](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101225124656AAu8Bjp) (since your OS is so old.)